# Will Brave New World disable my old mods?

Tags: civilization-5

I have a couple of mods, mostly custom civilizations, that were designed around G&K (Gods & Kings). Now that the new expansion is out, will installing the new expansion have unintended consequences for my old mods? If so, is there anyway to play with my old mods on the occasion that I feel like it?

Answer (score 1):

Your old mods will be disabled, but in the options screen of the game, you can change the current expansion to Gods and Kings. That will let you play your old mods when you want to.